# What are the default Apple URL schemes for the default apple apps?

Tags: ios, workflow, google-home

I am trying to track down these URLs because I would like to integrate them with the Shortcuts (previously workflow) app. My end game is to make queries that will perform certain functions that I can call from a google home device. In simpler terms, I want to make google home more "Apple friendly."

I have not found anything that is too current out there on the URL schemes. I saw that sending a SMS message was triggered with `sms://<PhoneNumber>` , but I am not sure how up to date that information is.

I plan on adding features to search Apple Music (by triggering a workflow). I am also planning on adding text message features.

I am also looking into making an app for google home, but I still am in the learning stage with that. Any advice on making google home more Apple friendly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What specific apps are you looking to open?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a constantly changing list given the number of features being added or third-party apps.  Here's a list that does a good job of staying up-to-date: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/always-updated-list-ios-app-url-scheme-names-0184033/

Comment: Awesome link! Is there an easy way to find out what you can pass into them? Also, is there an easy way to convert "problem characters" (such as spaces, periods, question marks, etc) to web address hex codes?

Comment: In terms of what you can paste in, each one is different.  Some the apps on that list have the example of how to use them (i.e. facetime://phone where phone is the phone number you would use).  Honestly with those that don't provide guidance, I've used trial and error. Some companies will provide guidance for what they expect to receive and how they want it packaged up.

If this solved your question, can please mark as answered?